# Database connectivity problem while making an android registration page?

Tags: java, android

Please help me in this code. Database is created successfully, table is also created successfully but record is not going into the table. It is showing successfull registration but not showing any record in the table.  here below i have attached the code of different class.

registrationalumini.java

```
public class RegistrationAlumini extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText first, last, email, mobile, currentjob, currentcity, currentcomp, dob,poy,feedback;
    Button save, cancel;
    DatabaseHandler db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_alumini);

        first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editfirstname);
        last = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editlastname);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editemail);
        mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editmobileno);
        currentjob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcurrentjob);
        currentcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcurrentcity);
        currentcomp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcurrentcompany);
        dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editdob);
        poy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpoy);
        feedback = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editfb);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String edfirst = first.getText().toString();
                String edlast = last.getText().toString();
                String edemail = email.getText().toString();
                String edmobile = mobile.getText().toString();
                String edcurrentjob = currentjob.getText().toString();
                String edcurrentcity = currentcity.getText().toString();
                String edcurrentcomp = currentcomp.getText().toString();
                String eddob = dob.getText().toString();
                String edpoy = poy.getText().toString();
                String edfeedback = feedback.getText().toString();

                if(first.getText().toString().length()==0 ){
                    first.setError("First name not entered");
                    first.requestFocus();
                }
                if(last.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    last.setError("Last name not entered");
                    last.requestFocus();
                }

                if(email.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    email.setError("Email is required");
                    email.requestFocus();
                }
                if(mobile.getText().toString().length()<10 ){
                    mobile.setError("Mobile number shall be 10 digit");
                    mobile.requestFocus();
                }
                if(currentjob.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    currentjob.setError("Current job is required");
                    currentjob.requestFocus();
                }
                if(currentcity.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    currentcity.setError("Current city is required");
                    currentcity.requestFocus();
                }
                if(currentcomp.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    currentcomp.setError("current company or organization is required");
                    currentcomp.requestFocus();
                }

                if(dob.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    dob.setError("date of birth is required");
                    dob.requestFocus();
                }
                if(poy.getText().toString().length()==0 ){
                    poy.setError("pass out year is required ");
                    poy.requestFocus();
                }
                if(feedback.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    feedback.setError("Feedback is required");
                    feedback.requestFocus();
                }

                db = new DatabaseHandler(RegistrationAlumini.this, null, null, 2);
                Registerdata reg = new Registerdata();

                reg.setfirstName(edfirst);
                reg.setlastName(edlast);
                reg.setEmailId(edemail);
                reg.setmobileno(edmobile);
                reg.setcurrentjob(edcurrentjob);
                reg.setcurrentcity(edcurrentcity);
                reg.setcurrentcomp(edcurrentcomp);
                reg.setdob(eddob);
                reg.setpoy(edpoy);
                reg.setfeedback(edfeedback);
                db.addregister(reg);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegistrationAlumini.class));
            }

        });

    }
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    int id;
    public DatabaseHandler(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Alumini.db";
    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_REGISTER= "register";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = " first_name";
    public static final String KEY_lAST_NAME = "last_name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL_ID="email_id";
    public static final String KEY_MOB_NO = "mobile_number";
    public static final String KEY_CURRENT_JOB = "current_job";
    public static final String KEY_CURRENT_CITY = "current_city";
    public static final String KEY_CURRENT_COMP = "current_comp";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH = "d_o_b";
    public static final String KEY_PASS_OUT_YEAR = "p_o_y";
    public static final String KEY_FEED_BACK = "feed_back";
    //public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REGISTER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"+KEY_lAST_NAME + " TEXT,"+KEY_EMAIL_ID+ " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MOB_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_CURRENT_JOB+ " TEXT ," + KEY_CURRENT_CITY+"TEXT,"+KEY_CURRENT_COMP+"TEXT,"+
            KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH+"TEXT,"+ KEY_PASS_OUT_YEAR+"TEXT,"+KEY_FEED_BACK+"TEXT"+")";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REGISTER);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    void addregister(Registerdata registerdata)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME,registerdata.getFirst_name()); // register first Name
        values.put(KEY_lAST_NAME, registerdata. getLast_name() ); // register last name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL_ID, registerdata.getEmail_id());//register email id
        values.put(KEY_MOB_NO, registerdata.getMobile_number());//register mobile no
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_JOB,registerdata.getCurrent_job()); // register current job
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_CITY, registerdata. getCurrent_city() ); // register current city
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_COMP, registerdata.getCurrent_comp());//register current company
        values.put(KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH, registerdata.getD_o_b());//register date of year
        values.put(KEY_PASS_OUT_YEAR, registerdata.getP_o_y());//register pass out year
        values.put(KEY_FEED_BACK, registerdata.getFeed_back());//register feedback
        //values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, registerdata.getPassword());
        // Inserting Row

        db.insert(TABLE_REGISTER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        }
```

RegisterData.java

```
public class Registerdata {

    int _id;
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    String email_id;
    String mobile_number;
    String current_job;
    String current_city;
    String current_comp;
    String d_o_b;
    String p_o_y;
    String feed_back;

    public Registerdata(){

    }

    public Registerdata(int id, String first_name, String  last_name,String email_id,String mobile_number, String current_job,
                        String current_city, String current_comp, String d_o_b, String p_o_y, String feed_back){
        this._id = id;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email_id=email_id;
        this.mobile_number=mobile_number;
        this.current_job = current_job;
        this.current_city = current_city;
        this.current_comp = current_comp;
        this.d_o_b = d_o_b;
        this.p_o_y = p_o_y;
        this.feed_back = feed_back;
    }
    public  int getID(){ return this._id; }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    public String getFirst_name() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return first_name;
    }
    // setting  first name
    public void setfirstName(String first_name){
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name(){
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setlastName(String last_name){
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getEmail_id(){
        return email_id;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String email_id){
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }
    public String getMobile_number(){
        return mobile_number;
    }
    public void setmobileno(String mobile_number){
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
    }
    public String getCurrent_job(){
        return current_job;
    }
    public void setcurrentjob(String current_job){
        this.current_job = current_job;
    }
    public String getCurrent_city(){
        return current_city;
    }
    public void setcurrentcity(String current_city){
        this.current_city = current_city;
    }
    public String getCurrent_comp(){
        return current_comp;
    }
    public void setcurrentcomp(String current_comp){
        this.current_comp = current_comp;
    }
    public String getD_o_b(){
        return d_o_b;
    }
    public void setdob(String d_o_b){
        this.d_o_b = d_o_b;
    }
    public String getP_o_y(){
        return p_o_y;
    }
    public void setpoy(String p_o_y){
        this.p_o_y = p_o_y;
    }
    public String getFeed_back(){
        return feed_back;
    }
    public void setfeedback(String feed_back){
        this.feed_back = feed_back;
    }
}

here is log 

2020-10-08 20:30:43.326 13701-13701/com.lcit.lcitnewdemo E/SQLiteLog: (1) table register has no column named feed_back in "INSERT INTO register( first_name,feed_back,id,mobile_number,d_o_b,p_o_y,current_job,email_id,current_city,current_comp,last_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2020-10-08 20:30:43.328 13701-13701/com.lcit.lcitnewdemo E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting  first_name=dfdsfdf feed_back=vcxvxcv id=0 mobile_number=1232322344 d_o_b=12-09-1986 p_o_y=2009 current_job=xvcvcv email_id=zczc@ghgh.com current_city=xcvxvx current_comp=xcvxcv last_name=xxcvxv
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table register has no column named feed_back (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO register( first_name,feed_back,id,mobile_number,d_o_b,p_o_y,current_job,email_id,current_city,current_comp,last_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1699)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
        at com.lcit.lcitnewdemo.DatabaseHandler.addregister(DatabaseHandler.java:74)
        at com.lcit.lcitnewdemo.RegistrationAlumini$1.onClick(RegistrationAlumini.java:108)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7438)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7415)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28286)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
2020-10-08 20:30:43.329 13701-13701/com.lcit.lcitnewdemo D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10163; state: ENABLED
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining the table in `CREATE_TABLE` you forgot to add some spaces in `"TEXT"`. You should have gotten an exception when it attempted to create a table. I corrected it here:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REGISTER + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"+KEY_lAST_NAME + " TEXT,"+KEY_EMAIL_ID+ " TEXT,"
        + KEY_MOB_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_CURRENT_JOB+ " TEXT ," + KEY_CURRENT_CITY+" TEXT,"+KEY_CURRENT_COMP+" TEXT,"+
        KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH+" TEXT,"+ KEY_PASS_OUT_YEAR+" TEXT,"+KEY_FEED_BACK+" TEXT"+")";
```